# error 503: "client denied by server configuration" after shopware update

Tags: apache, shopware

after the update from shopware5.1 to shopware 5.2, I get the the error message "503 Service Unavailable" on each page. Looking into the error.log file it says to me:

"[Mon Jan 16 12:37:55.555394 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 19443:tid 139770345473792] [client xyz] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/abc/www.xyz.com/anotherpath".

However, the path "anotherpath" does not exist. I assume it is coming from the htaccess that is in the folder www.xyz.com. Do you have any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Shopware error reporting. It will show detailed error message. Refer [Debugging in Shopware](http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1912.html)

Comment: Finally after having the debugging information, it was an easy way to solve it. It was basically a plugin error. Thank you :-)